# I want to populate an element in output xml based on template

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am new in XSLT. So maybe my question is not cleared,  I have below xml file for the index and want to transform xml as below expected output.

```
<root>
<para>absgx</para>
<para>&#x2013; abcd asjdsaj AD I.</para>
<para>&#x2013; abcd asjdsaj AD II.12.5, I.abc.</para>
<para>&#x2013; abcd asjdsaj AD Ibis.aass.</para>
<para>absgx</para>
<para>absgx</para>
<para>&#x2013; abcd asjdsaj AD II.</para>
<para>&#x00B0; abcd asjdsaj AD I.a</para>
<para>&#x00B0; abcd asjdsaj AD I.b</para>
<para>&#x2013; abcd asjdsaj AD II.</para>
<para>&#x2013; abcd asjdsaj AD III.</para>
<para>absgx</para>
</root>
```

expected output:

```
 <root>
<index>
<title/>
<indexdiv>
<title/>
<indexentry>
<primaryie>absgx</primaryie>
<secondaryie>&#x2013; abcd asjdsaj AD <pg>I.</pg></secondaryie>
    <secondaryie>&#x2013; abcd asjdsaj AD <pg>II.12.5</pg></secondaryie>
    <secondaryie>&#x2013; abcd asjdsaj AD <pg>Ibis.aass.</pg></secondaryie>
</indexentry>
<indexentry>
<primaryie>absgx</primaryie>
</indexentry>
<indexentry>
<primaryie>absgx</primaryie>
    <secondaryie>&#x2013; abcd asjdsaj AD <pg>II.</pg></secondaryie>
    <tertryie level="1">&#x00B0; abcd asjdsaj AD <pg>I.a</pg></tertryie>
    <tertryie level="1">&#x00B0; abcd asjdsaj AD <pg>I.b</pg></tertryie>
    <secondaryie>&#x2013; abcd asjdsaj AD <pg>II.</pg></secondaryie>
    <secondaryie>&#x2013; abcd asjdsaj AD <pg>III.</pg></secondaryie>
</indexentry>
<indexentry>
<primaryie>absgx</primaryie>
</indexentry>
</indexdiv>
</index>
</root>
```

Almost I have done but I am unable to generate "indexentry" with each "primaryie" element. Below is my XSLT:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
        version="2.0">

        <xsl:output method="xml"/>

        <xsl:template match="*|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="para">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=".[starts-with(.,'&#x2013;')]">
                    <xsl:element name="secondaryie">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:element>   
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=".[starts-with(., '&#x00B0;')]">
                    <xsl:element name="tertryie">
                        <xsl:attribute name="level" select="1"></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:element name="primaryie">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="text()">
           <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="I.*">
               <xsl:matching-substring>
                   <xsl:element name="pg">
                       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                   </xsl:element>
               </xsl:matching-substring>
               <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                   <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
               </xsl:non-matching-substring>
           </xsl:analyze-string> 
        </xsl:template>


    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

So please suggest how we populate "indexentry".

Comment: If the contents like `<para>absgx</para>` are known and meant to start an `indexentry` "group" this seems like a job for `<xsl:for-each-group select="para" group-starting-with="para[. = 'absgx']"><indexentry><primaryie>absgx</primaryie>` where I think the other grouping can also be done with nested `for-each-group select="current-group()" group-starting-with="para[starts-with(.,'&#x2013;')]"`

Comment: @MartinHonnen, <para>absgx</para> text not fixed, this maybe different on each para

Comment: What are the criteria to transform a `para` into an `indexentry` wrapper element with a  `primaryie` child?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, we need indexentry with each primary element  as:
<indexentry>
<primaryie>a</primaryie>
<secondaryie>aass</secondaryie>
</indexentry>
<indexenrty>
<primaryie>aasd</primaryie>
</indexenrty>

Comment: Means: In one indexenrty, one primaryie is allowed